# In Java when i parse an XML to Object how can i annotate my element which should be my Class and not my rootElement for an XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, annotations, unmarshalling

I have an xml which is looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
    <flight flight="LX179" dep="SIN" arr="ZRH" aircraftRegistration="HBJMN"
    paxWeight="10000" />    
</input>
```

And i used jaxb to unmarshall it to an object

So my class looks like this , if i delete the input tag from the xml, and make  the Public Class Flight to my @RootElement, then it works fine, but thats not good for me, i need them there... pls could anyone help with this ?

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "input")


@XmlElement     //I GOT THE ERROR HERE
public class Flight {

private String flight,dep,arr,aircraftRegistration;
private int paxWeight;


public Flight() {
}

 public Flight(String flight, String dep, String arr, String aircraftRegistration, 
 int paxWeight, ) {
    this.flight = flight;
    this.dep = dep;
    this.arr = arr;
    this.aircraftRegistration = aircraftRegistration;
    this.paxWeight = paxWeight;


 public String getFlight() {
    return flight;
}


@XmlAttribute
public void setFlight(String flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
}

public String getDep() {
    return dep;
}
@XmlAttribute
public void setDep(String dep) {
    this.dep = dep;
}

public String getArr() {
    return arr;
}
@XmlAttribute
public void setArr(String arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
}

public String getAircraftRegistration() {
    return aircraftRegistration;
}
@XmlAttribute
public void setAircraftRegistration(String aircraftRegistration) {
    this.aircraftRegistration = aircraftRegistration;
}

public int getPaxWeight() {
    return paxWeight;
}
@XmlAttribute
public void setPaxWeight(int paxWeight) {
    this.paxWeight = paxWeight;
}
```

My parsing method

```
 private void beolvasas() {


    try {
        File file = new File("/input.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Input.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
       Input flight = (Input) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        flightList.add(flight);

    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }   

}

private void kiir() {
    for (Input input : flightList) {
        System.out.println(input);

    }
}
```

My Input class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Input {

private Flight flight;

@XmlRootElement
public class Input {


private List<Flight> lista;

public Input() {
}

public Input(List<Flight> list) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

public List<Flight> getList() {
    return lista;
}

@XmlElement
public void setList(List<Flight> list) {
    this.lista = list;
}
```

This is the last xml File...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<masterdata>
<airlines>
    <airline id="1" name="Lufthansa" code="LH" minUnderload="1000"/>
    <airline id="2" name="Swiss" code="LX" minUnderload="500" />
</airlines>

<aircraftTypes>
    <aircraftType id="380" name="Airbus 380-800" maxZFW="361000" maxLAW="386000"                      maxTOW="560000" maxTXW="562000" maxFuel="256000"/>        <aircraftType id="747" name="Boeing 747-8"   maxZFW="295289" maxLAW="312072" maxTOW="447696" maxTXW="449056" maxFuel="193280"/>
    <aircraftType id="340" name="Airbus 340-600" maxZFW="245000" maxLAW="259000" maxTOW="368000" maxTXW="369200" maxFuel="163600"/>
</aircraftTypes>

<aircrafts>
    <aircraft id="11"  ownerAirlineId="1" registration="DAIML" typeId="380" startw="276800"  />
    <aircraft id="12"  ownerAirlineId="1" registration="DABVT" typeId="747" startw="162400"  />
    <aircraft id="13"  ownerAirlineId="1" registration="DAIHQ" typeId="340" startw="177020"  />

    <aircraft id="21"  ownerAirlineId="2" registration="HBJMN" typeId="340" startw="176445"  />
</aircrafts>
```

Comment: If you delete which tag? It's very unclear what the problem is. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry i mean if i delete the input tag

Comment: Why don't you just refactor and have a POJO for `<input>` which contains a `Flight` (or more)?

Comment: Do you mean to make Input class instead that contains the Flight ?

Comment: Make an `Input` class and a `Flight` class. Have the `Input` class contain a variable of type `Flight`.

Comment: Sorry for this noob question but if i have more than one flight in my xml, how can i parse it, because now it only parse one.

Comment: I copied my parsing method to the end of the question

Comment: You can have a `List<Flight>`

Comment: yes but it contains only the first flight element from my xml

Comment: So your XML contains many `<flight>` elements inside `<input>`? A variable of type `List<Flight>` instead of a single `Flight` should work.

Comment: Yes my xml contains more Flight element, and yes i made list for them and i edited the code above if you check, but it only puts into the list the first Flight element and thats all.

Comment: Post your new `Input` class.

Comment: OKay its there, should i make a FLight list in there ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Model your Java POJOs after your XML and vice versa. Your XML contains an outer `Inner` element and many `Flight` elements, so your Java should have an `Inner` element with many `Flight` elements. How do you model _many_? You use a `List`, `Set`, or array.

Comment: Sorry but i dont really get it, i changed my INput class so you can see it above, i made a Flight List. but where should i add the flights to the List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You theoretically have this

```
<input>
    <flight flight="LX179" dep="SIN" arr="ZRH" aircraftRegistration="HBJMN"
    paxWeight="10000" />    
    <flight flight="LX178" dep="SIN" arr="YUL" aircraftRegistration="ABCDE"
    paxWeight="10000" />  
</input>
```

Therefore you have a collection of `<flight>` elements within one `<input>` element. You have to model that with Java.

```
public class Input {
    public List<Flight> lista;
}
public class Flight {}
```

Once you have that, you have to add the appropriate annotations. `<input>` is the root element, so `Input` should be a root element.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "input")
public class Input {
```

It has a collection of elements called `<flight>`, so that field should be annotated

```
@XmlElement(name = "flight")
public List<Flight> lista;
```

Comment: Ah @Sotirios Sorry but i stucked again with my last XML file(i copied into the end of the question), i tried to move on the logic what you showed before, but here i need a `masterdata` class which will be the rootelement this class has a `airlines`,`aircraftTypes`, and `aircrafts` class and the annotated as `Xmlelement` and for theese Classes each has `List<airline>`, `List<aircraftType>`, etc, and thes are annotated as Xmlelement too ? and at the end i got the basic airline, aircraft and aircraftType classses with the properties ?

Comment: @gua That XML (as shown) isn't valid. You can only have one root element.

Comment: Are you sure ? So there is no chance to parse it in this structure ?

Comment: @gua You need valid XML.